# Sorting a list of list such that last element of a list equals first element of next list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists which is

```
my_list=[[9, 10, 1], [1, 7, 5, 6, 11], [0, 4], [4, 2, 9]]
```

I want to sort this list such that it looks like this:

```
result=[[0, 4], [4, 2, 9],[9, 10, 1], [1, 7, 5, 6, 11]]
```

The conditions are:
1. The list should start with the element containing zero.
2. The last element of a list should be same as first element of the next list and so on.
3. The elements inside the sub-lists should be in the same order as the original list.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the condition is possible?

Comment: Please make it clear what you want. What if there is no such ordering? (e.g., `[[0,1],[2,3]]`)

Comment: What if there are multiple possible orderings? Like `[[0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]`?

Comment: Yes such a condition will always be possible, and the ordering in the sub-lists must be same as the original list.

Comment: This isn't a question; it's just a request for code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey this will not happen in my case as the elements in the list will not repeat.

Comment: Well, the elements in the sublists don't necessarily have to repeat. Something like `[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 1]]` also has more than 1 solution.

Comment: you can create a dictionary, where you can map every possible previous to next and then simple travere everything possible and stop once you get length same as the old one. Try it!

Comment: @Aran-Fey Any element in the list repeats at-most once so there will be a single solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for each permutation of your list, if they are a valid permutation. It might be possible to write a more efficient algorithm, but this one does not assume that there is exactly one possible solution.

```
from itertools import permutations

my_list=[[9, 10, 1], [1, 7, 5, 6, 11], [0, 4], [4, 2, 9]]

def sortCheck(a):
    if a[0][0] != 0:
        return False

    for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
        if a[i][-1] != a[i+1][0]:
            return False
    return True

result_list = []

for permutation in permutations(my_list):
    if sortCheck(permutation):
        result_list.append(list(permutation))
```

Answer (score 1):

The fast solution is to build a dict that maps numbers to sublists based on the first element:

```
dct = {sublist[0]: sublist for sublist in my_list}
# {0: [0, 4], 9: [9, 10, 1], 1: [1, 7, 5, 6, 11], 4: [4, 2, 9]}
```

And then, starting with the number 0, looking up the next sublist that needs to be added in the dict:

```
result = []
num = 0  # start with the sublist where the first element is 0
while True:
    try:
        # find the sublist that has `num` as the first element
        sublist = dct[num]
    except KeyError:
        # if there is no such sublist, we're done
        break

    # add the sublist to the result and update `num`
    result.append(sublist)
    num = sublist[-1]
```

This runs in linear `O(n)` time and gives the expected results:

```
[[0, 4], [4, 2, 9], [9, 10, 1], [1, 7, 5, 6, 11]]
```

Comment: If you have several sublists starting with the same element, only the last one will be stored in `dct`, which is not what the OP asks for

Comment: @sciroccorics The OP already confirmed that that can't happen.

Comment: Your solution is much more beautiful and effective (and/but more specific) than mine, but calling it "the smart solution" implies that other solutions are "not smart", which in my opinion is a bit rude. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice implementation, but it works:

```
my_list=[[9, 10, 1], [1, 7, 5, 6, 11], [0, 4], [4, 2, 9]]

new_list = []
index = 0
while my_list:
    index = [item[0] for item in my_list].index(index)
    item = my_list[index]
    del my_list[index]
    new_list.append(item)
    index = item[-1]
print(new_list)
```

A `ValueError` is raised when no sublist is found that meet the criterion

Answer (score 0):

```
    def sortList(list)
      hash = {}
      list.each do |value|
        hash[value[0]] = value
      end
      key = 0
      sorted = []
      list.each do |k|
        item = hash[key.to_i]
        key = item[-1]
        sorted << item
      end
      sorted
    end
```